# R and Shiny: Making sure different tabs display different heatmaps

Tags: r, user-interface, shiny

**BACKGROUND** I have just one problem with a mostly functional Shiny app in **R** that generates and appropriately labels tabs depending on user input. The tabs shown in the app represent different 'slices' of an input dataset, which are chosen by the user from a checkbox UI. Each tab contains the same four kinds of output heatmaps since the function for producing the heatmaps is invariant across tabs.

**PROBLEM** These heatmaps *should* differ from tab to tab because the input 'slice' *should* differ across tabs. But the heatmaps currently do *not* vary. Rather, the heatmaps for tab *N* display across all tabs. I would like to hear your thoughts on how to ensure that the heatmaps and tabs reflect my desired differences.

**OBSERVATIONS** The data slices that go into each tab do differ across tabs as desired, as reflected in the CSVs output by the aforementioned loop. Also, just to cite two examples, running the loop only `for (i in 1:1)` or `for (i in 3:3)` results in two correct and different sets of heatmaps. Lastly, if run outside the Shiny environment and sequentially and manually given the CSVs just mentioned, `plotReport()` does output the right plots for the right CSV.

**SUSPICIONS** Given these observations, it is likely that the last iteration of the loop overrides all previous iterations.

**SERVER.R CODE** The excerpt below features a `for()` loop that generates the tabs, names them, writes CSVs of the data that go into the the four heatmaps of each tab, and then uses the custom function `plotReports()` to generate the heatmaps. The heatmaps are then assigned to the right tabs.

```
  options(shiny.maxRequestSize=300*1024^2)
  options(shiny.fullstacktrace = TRUE)

  shinyServer(function(input, output) {

    # Data inputs
    dataInput <- eventReactive(input$goButton, {

    # A lot of code, removed here for clarity

    # Dynamic tabbing
    output$tabs <- renderUI({

      # behavior and sales tabs
      tabs <- list(NULL)
      tabs[[1]] <- tabPanel("Sales", plotOutput("salesPlot"))
      tabs[[2]] <- tabPanel("Behavior", plotOutput("behaviorPlot"))

      # result tabs
      result.list <- dataInput()[[6]]
      name.list <- dataInput()[[7]]
      #browser()
      print("length")
      print(length(result.list))
      print(length(name.list))
      for (i in 1 : length(result.list)) {
          print(i)
          output[[paste("rep", i, sep='')]] <- renderPlot({
            result <- result.list[[i]]
            print(result)
            write.csv(result, paste('result', i, '.csv', sep = ''))
            plotReports(result, input)
        })
        tabs[[2 + i]] <- tabPanel(name.list[[i]], plotOutput(paste("rep", i, sep='')))
        #browser()
      }
      do.call(tabsetPanel, tabs)
    })

  })
```

**PLOTREPORTS() CODE**

```
plotReports <- function(result, input) {

  # row and column
  x <- seq(input$res, input$max.benefit.limit, input$res)
  y <- seq(0, input$target.limit, input$res)

  # make matrix
  A <- matrix(result$reach, nrow = length(x), ncol = length(y))
  B <- matrix(result$cost, nrow = length(x), ncol = length(y))
  C <- matrix(result$sales.increase, nrow = length(x), ncol = length(y))
  D <- matrix(result$roi, nrow = length(x), ncol = length(y))

  # plot
  par(mfrow = c(2, 2))
  par(mar=c(5, 5, 4, 10))
  image.plot(x, y, A, xlab = "Max Benefit", ylab = "Target", main = "Reach", col = cm.colors(256))
  image.plot(x, y, B, xlab = "Max Benefit", ylab = "Target", main = "Cost", col = cm.colors(256))
  image.plot(x, y, C, xlab = "Max Benefit", ylab = "Target", main = "Sales Increase", col = cm.colors(256))
  image.plot(x, y, D, xlab = "Max Benefit", ylab = "Target", main = "Return of Investment", col = cm.colors(256))
}
```

Comment: I suppose a related question is, Does renderPlot() render immediately when called or only once the loop in which it called has iterated fully?